# Returning data from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, freebase

I'm writing my first directive in angular- it's essentially just a wrapper on the freebase search widget written in jquery.

I want to make the directive application independent (with the only dependencies being external css and jquery).

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOANCuzwCOlDlxEefSDr?p=preview) of the directive as it is now.

And the directive itself:

```
directive('suggest', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: "<input type='text'>",
      replace:true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var language = 'en'; //set english as default language
        if (attrs.lang){
          language = attrs.lang;
          attrs.$observe('lang', function(value) {
            console.log("lang val " + value);
            language = value;
          });
        }
        $(element).suggest({
          "lang": language
        })
        .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) { 
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
  };
});
```

When the user selects an item from the dropdown menu, the following function runs:

```
.bind("fb-select", function(e, data) { 
          console.log(data);
        });
```

What is the best practice for feeding the data from the selection to the application thats using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most angular way would be to achieve this using data binding (2 way) in an isolated scope:

```
 restrict: 'E',
      template: "<input type='text'>",
      replace:true,
      scope:{
         myModel:'='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      ............
```

and inside that select function:

```
.bind("fb-select", function(e, data) { 
          console.log(data);
          scope.myModel=data;
});
```

usage:

`<suggest my-model="someModel" .... />`

and in your controller $scope:

`$scope.someModel="";`

You still need to handle the initial binding for that pre-selected model in your directive though, but yea, the cleanest way is 2 way data binding through an isolate scope.

EDIT

These 2 articles are excellent for helping port jquery plugins to angular:

http://rogerz.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/jQuery-to-angularjs/

http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain what you mean when you say I need to handle the initial binding in the directive? Are you referring to the scope.myModel=data; line?

Comment: @bornytm what is this directive supposed to do? i.e. the desired behaviour? There are a few things to point out, you're passing `lang` through an isolate scope in your directive definition, but then you're watching it with `attrs.$observe`, if it's passed through a scope you use `scope.$watch`, `attrs.$observe` is for watching attribute parameters not scope parameters. I suggest you take a look around to see how angular directives are created, plenty of nice blogs out there.

Comment: Also definitely take a look at those 2 links.

Comment: The purpose is to allow users to tag content within the application with terms fetched from freebase.

With the directive I would like to be able to pass in the language with which to perform the query as an attribute on the element and to get the data returned from the freebase query to the application. I definitely have more reading to do on directives (as I said, this is the first one I'm trying). Thanks for the links and your help.